# Check for window dimensions in PyGame / SDL

Tags: sdl, pygame, window-managers

Is there another way to get the window's dimensions other than `pygame.display.Info()` or the surface `pygame.display.set_mode()` returns?

I'm developing a piece of software with resizable window. While setting a default dimensions is ok for most window managers out there, the tiling ones (such as Awesome, Xmonad, etc) agressively fit the window into a dynamic size of their choice. This refitting happens so fast after SDL creates the initial window, it doesn't generate `pygame.VIDEORESIZE` event with the new (correct) dimensions.

Now things work well if at start I generate a bogus videoresize event with new size of 0:

```
P.event.post(P.event.Event(P.VIDEORESIZE, size=(0,0), w=0, h=0))
```

At least Xmonad will see this and resize again with a good size. I have a hunch it won't be as pretty with the traditional window managers. Probably the window gets to cover all of the screen estate.

Is there a better way to determine frame sizes?

Comment: `pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()`

Comment: @monkey: nope. Reports the same as the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Under pygame.event.get() there is event.size, event.h and event.w and that retrieves the windows dimensions

so for example I re-sized the background color by calling the even.w,event.h because otherwise the screen would re-size but I would get a white square. Also you can use list_modes and then use index to call which list you think you want from biggest to smallest so [0] is fullscreen

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type ==  QUIT:
        terminate()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
        terminate()
    elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
        displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h),RESIZABLE)
        displaysurf.fill(WHITE)
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_f:
        displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode(pygame.display.list_modes()[0],RESIZABLE)
        displaysurf.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.event.clear()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answers the wrong question. I have a VIDEORESIZE handler in place and it works after the launch. But it doesn't get called properly in the very beginning of my window creation.